# MRTK Figma Bridge Import tool not working?

Tags: unity-game-engine, figma

I'm trying to import from Figma with the MRTK Figma Bridge inside Unity engine.
Unity 2021.2.8f1
MRTK Figma Bridge 0.1.1
MRTK Standard Assets 2.7.3
MRTK Tools 2.7.3
OpenXR Plugin 1.2.1

When I import the page from Figma, all objects are empty objects except the TextMeshPro objects. This leads me to believe that there is some sort of disconnect between the prefabs that are being used in Figma vs the prefabs in the project (MRTK standard assets). My question is, Am I using the incorrect versions for this to work? am I doing something wrong?

To Reproduce:
Mixed Reality menu > Toolkit > MRTK Figma Bridge > Figma Bridge Window > from here I enter my token, Load Files, and then Build Page 1 (currently only have one page). at this point the page is added to the Hierarchy of the scene, but like I said all objects are empty except the TextMeshPro objects.

No errors are presented upon building of the pages.